# Text (@font-face: *.woff) rendering with gaps

Tags: css, firefox, rendering, font-face, text-rendering

I use a custom `.woff` for my font. However mid-word it adds wig gaps (think tab, tab, tab).

I can't screenshot because of low reputation, but the basic effect is:

```
"He                 llo I'm trying t                 o type a sen          tence he          re"
```

Instead of

```
"Hello I'm trying to type a sentence here"
```

In chrome I fixed the issue with:

```
a, body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  text-rendering: optimizeSpeed !important;
}
```

But firefox doesn't have that rendering option, meaning I can't fix it there.

Any leads are appreciated.

Additional info:

- I use only woff, converted from a ttf
- The ttf alone doesn't work
- The font is Eurostile

Comment: Note that stackoverflow removes a lot of space in the text, the gaps are the size of 2-3 words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you use different extensions for different purposes. As different browser does not render fonts the same way.

There are way to generate these fonts into .ttf/.eot/svg formats

Ideally the font css should be of all formats like this

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.0.3') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.0.3') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.0.3#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

In the end, sometimes the font is not good enough that it do not render correctly then you would have to fallback to google fonts.

I used theses in the past

http://everythingfonts.com/otf-to-eot
http://www.font2web.com/

However my problem was different, it was that the font was not high-def enough. 
For your case it might just be the font-type works differently for different browsers

Do let me know of the results!
Good Luck